# Play, Anorm and PostgreSQL: Problems with serial columns?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, postgresql-9.1, anorm

I used Play 2.1.0 with anorm, Scala 2.10 and PostgreSQL (9.1, driver: 9.1-901.jdbc4). The following query worked fine in MySQL. After moving to PostgreSQL it doesn't. After entering the method, there is an "exception" thrown in line "implicit connection", i.d. the debugger jumps right to Sql.resultSetToStream line 527, where obviously the metadata of the columns are determined. In the Play logs there is no error shown...

The id field was in MySql an integer and in PostgreSQL it is a serial. Does Anorm has a problem with serial columns?

```
def getUserId(userName: String): Int = {
DB.withConnection {
  implicit connection =>
    try {
      val result = SQL("select  id from users where user_name = {userName}")
        .on('userName -> userName).apply().head
      result[Int]("id")
    } catch {
      case e: SQLException =>
        Logger.error(e.getStackTraceString)
        //error logged, but no problem when we return 0
        0
    }
  }
 }
```

I've got the same problem with an insert statement in the same table.

The interesting thing is that the following query works:

```
def checkCredentials(userName: String, password: String): Boolean = {
DB.withConnection {
  implicit connection =>
    try {
      val result = SQL("select count(*) as c from users where user_name = {userName} and password = crypt({password}, password)")
        .on('userName -> userName,
          'password -> password).apply().head
      result[Long]("c") > 0
    } catch {
      case e: SQLException =>
        Logger.error(e.getStackTraceString)
        false
    }
}
```

Comment: Is a serial not a `Long` type?

Comment: No, I once read it is an int. But the problem occurs when the sql in fact would return no row. But I don't understand why a "no row" result is no problem in MySQL, but is one in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the id column. Apparently PostgreSQL considers this as a function word, so if you put it between ' ' then it works, this means writing  'id' solves the problem.